# Database for video sharing website

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I am building a simple database for a video sharing site. What video-related fields should the table include? The following are what I can think of --

```
VIDEOS
title
uploader (many-to-many)
category (one-to-many)
privacy (one-tomany)
tags (one-to-many)
upload_timestamp
length
views
likes
flags
original_file (another table -- size, codec, aspect ratio, etc.)
tagged_credits (another table -- name / position)
```

The functionality of video sharing is pretty basic -- related videos / ability to like / shows credits of individuals involved with the video.

Does this seem like a good structure for the video-related section? Are there any columns that I'm missing (or misrepresenting)? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be smart to break the website functionality away from the video object you built here.  The video should contain any data about the actual video file itself (length, size, resolution, codec, aspect ratio, etc) and the item you defined here should be agnostic as to what its contents are. So you can have an item now that has an uploader, category, privacy, tags, timestamp, etc (but not length).  That way you can change it later to allow for image uploads, song uploads, and not be bound to a length or an object called a video (that could potentially be not a video)